# Django : rendering a TemplateView in another

Tags: django

Using Django, I have multiple template files (A, B and C) that could be rendered in the same TemplateView called GenericView.

A, B and C uses the same View (let's call it DynamicView), therefore I need to call the rendering method of this DynamicView from GenericView's get_context_data`.

Is there a way I can render easily DynamicView's template within GenericView's template?

EDIT : I am using class based view coding

EDIT : Added some code to make my question clearer :

Here is my GenericView :

```
class GenericView(DetailView):
    model = SimpleModel
    template_name = "template.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(GenericView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        tests = DynamicModel.objects.filter(test=context['object'].pk)
        context['tests'] = tests
        print("tests : ", tests[0]) # each test contains a field called "template_path", I would like to instanciate a DynamicView so that I can include the rendered page in context
        return context

class DynamicView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "dummy.html"
    model = DynamicModel

    def render_to_response(self, context, **kwargs):
        absolute_path = get_object_or_404(DynamicModel, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        page = render(self.request, absolute_path, context, content_type=None, status=None, using=None) # here the page is rendered
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override DynamicView's [get_template_names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names) method.

Before doing that though, what is being considered in making the decision on what template to render? It might be better to make 3 different views, use inheritance to let them share code and not rework any of that view routing.

Comment: A, B and C were just examples actually, there can be as many as I want, but they are all rendered my the same DynamicView. I already overrode "render_to_response" method from this class so that I can chose which of A, B or C I have to render and how

Comment: The problem is more about how to include the rendered DynamicView page in the GenericView really

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done with the [Django template tag.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) You need to call `render` function inside of this tag and put it inside of needed template.

EDIT after code updates.

```
from django import template
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from myapp.models import DynamicModel

register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag('dummy.html', takes_context=True)
def render_dynamic_model(context, **kwargs):
    absolute_path = get_object_or_404(DynamicModel, pk=kwargs['pk'])

    return {
       'absolute_path': absolute_path,
    }
```

And put it into template `template.html`

```
{% render_dynamic_model pk %}
```

This code like a general idea, if you need some variables from request, you can pass it in the template and update template tag code respectively.

```
{% render_dynamic_model pk request.user %}
```

Comment: okay, this seems promising! That wouldn't require to write more code in views I guess. I will post the result as soon as I can try it.

Comment: In my case, I am not sure how to call render. The input I have is the absolute_url of the DynamicView model object (A, B or C).

Comment: @aze please provide more code. It is hard to guess solution you need.

Comment: I added some code hopefully it will make the question clearer

Comment: It does not seem to work, I received an error TemplateDoesNotExist for 'dummy.html' . In my code it is actually never used since the template to use is rendered directly.
I tried your code but it didn't seem to call any method of DynamicView.

Comment: because you have to specify full path to the template  'dummy.html'. For example 'apps/core/dummy.html'

Comment: It doesn't actually exist, its a dummy name, I don't need it in DynamicView since I am manually rendering the page with a dynamic path.